# How to get attribute from json list based on another attribute?

Tags: c#, json

I have a json response consisting of a list of objects. Each object has an `id` and `name`

For example: `[{"id":1,"name":"Joe"},{"id":2,"name":"Mike"}]`

Without using models and deserialization, what's the easiest way to directly get a `name` given an `id`?

I need something like the following but that actually works:

`var name = JObject.Parse(json)["name"].Select(p => p["id"] == "1");`

Comment: You know that `1` is not a string in the JSON sample posted, right?

Comment: Your json is an array, yet you are parsing it as an object?

Comment: take a look at this link https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use JsonPaths for things like this. These are a couple good references for querying json with JsonPaths. http://jsonpath.com/ and https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2

```
var json = "[{ 'id':1,'name':'Joe'},{ 'id':2,'name':'Mike'}]";
var jObject = JArray.Parse(json);
JToken nameResult = jObject.SelectToken("$.[?(@.id == 1)]"); 
var jsonResult = nameResult["name"].ToString();
```

Comment: Sorry but this returns `{ 'id':1,'name':'Joe'}` not `Joe`, is there a mistake?

Comment: @JoeDefill yep I'm really bad about missing the specifics. updated to nameResult["name"]